# How to apply CSS to nested Unordered Lists?

Tags: html, css

I have some nested unordered list, I need to apply my class `ul-deactive` to every element inside that div with tag `<ul> <li>` at any depth.

With my code I'm not able to make it work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
<div class="ul-deactive">
<ul>
    <li>a
        <ul>
            <li>a-1 </li>
            <li>a-2 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul>
            <li>b-1 </li>
            <li>b-2 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
.ul-deactive ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color:Fuchsia;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: your code works for me. what exactly are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: Yep, I agree. `.ul-deactive ul li` selects any `li` which is a descendant (at any depth) of any `ul` which is a descendant (ditto) of an element with class `ul-deactive`

Comment: I'm able to apply the color but not to remove the margin and the  change the style-type

Comment: be aware that the ul has a margin as well by default

Comment: the styles are inherited so make sure you reset them for example:

`ul li { margin: 100px; }` to reset this you would add `ul li ul li { margin: 0px; }`

Comment: Works for me also. Do you have typo? Do you have style tag around your css? Is it in external file or in your html? If it is external how did you include it?

Comment: Thanks guys for your support, my code posted above was fine. I found out that the problem was with the CSS re-setter from YAHOO YUI 3. I updated to the latest version 3.4.0 and all is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties `list-style-type`, `margin`, and `padding` should be applied to the `ul`, not the `li`, like so:

```
.ul-deactive ul li
{
     color:Fuchsia;
} 

.ul-deactive ul
{
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
.ul-deactive ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.ul-deactive ul li
{
    color:Fuchsia;
}
```